# How to fetch the schema from Azure eventhub using Golang

Tags: go, avro, azure-eventhub

I have schema created in the eventhub, and I'm using "github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-go/v3" package to receive and send messages to eventhub using Go.

How can I use Schema to serialize/deserialize the data being sent or received?

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing schema doesn't depend on which Messaging queue is being used.

Inorder to fetch the avro schema we can use the standard `net/http` package as there are APIs which return the schema.

The URL would be of the below format:

**If the avro subject and version is known:**

```
https://<schema_registry_url>/subjects/<subject_name>/versions/<version_number>

If the latest version schema is required `<version_number>` can be replaced with `latest`
```

**If the schema id is known:**

```
https://<schema_registry_url>/schemas/ids/<id>
```